# AppBarTheme not applied with copyWith in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got this code snippet below trying to apply a title theme to my appBar and I am not quite sure I am understanding the copyWith function for the theme. My understanding would be that all properties of my theme are copied over, except those that I change. I am not changing appBarTheme when I use the copyWith, so why is it not applying to the app?

I've uncommented the line that does't work, and commented out the one that does.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ThemeData theme = ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
    fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
    // This doesn't work
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'OpenSans', fontSize: 40)),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Personal Expenses',
      theme: theme.copyWith(
        colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: Colors.amber),
        // This does work
        // appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        //     titleTextStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'OpenSans', fontSize: 40)),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not changing appBarTheme when I use the copyWith, so why is it
> not applying to the app?

What do you mean? If you want to simply apply your `theme` then all you have to do is [this](https://gist.github.com/nghtctrl/5588f7ca897f9a5450f5f809d6e07f2c).

Essentially,

```
MaterialApp(
  ...
  theme: theme
  ...
);
```

If you want to change the color of the AppBar, then you would want to do [this](https://gist.github.com/nghtctrl/1e0cd41c241414f5c51d3f8c2c3de63b).

Essentially,

```
MaterialApp(
  ...
  theme: theme.copyWith(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
  ),
  ...
);
```

This would allow you to change your AppBar color while leaving your AppBar's `titleTextStyle` as it is.

Please note that your code `theme.colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: Colors.amber)` will only set the secondary color, which will not be visible depending on how you setup your AppBar. I am not sure if you did this intentionally.

Finally, if you want to change the `appBarTheme` as well, then you would want to do [this](https://gist.github.com/nghtctrl/29dd16b910f556e5dace979cb547950e).

Essentially,

```
MaterialApp(
  ...
  theme: theme.copyWith(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
    appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
      titleTextStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'OpenSans', fontSize: 10),
    ),
  ),
  ...
);
```

Note that I only changed the font size from 40 to 10.

All these should work, and it should show very big differences in the UI. In other words, your code seems fine. I am not very sure why you think that it is "not applying to the app". Please clarify why you think so.

Comment: cleaning flutter and picking a different emulator worked. Not sure what was causing it :/ Your post made me dig deeper so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, I tested and it's working fine
[image]

```
 theme: theme.copyWith(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.redAccent,titleTextStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Amiri", fontSize: 40))
```

change the App bar theme but for

```
theme.copyWith(
    colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: Colors.amber),
```

it change secondary color not App bar theme